# How to test one variable in a panel for cross-section dependence?

Tags: r, econometrics, panel-data, plm

The `plm::pcdtest` function implements Pesaran, (2004) General Diagnostic Tests for Cross Section Dependence in Panels. For example a test for a panel model works as such:

```
data(Grunfeld, package = "plm")
## test on heterogeneous model (separate time series regressions)
pcdtest(inv ~ value + capital, data=Grunfeld,
    index = c("firm","year"))
```

But if I want to test the cross-section dependance of only one variable in the panel for example `inv` in the example above, how can I do it in R?

Answer (score 4):

As the test is applied to the residuals of the panel model, you could just regress on a constant, such that the residuals would be nothing but the demeaned variables whose cross-section dependence you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a `.pseries` method for `pcdtest`, hence the following works:

```
library(plm)
data(Grunfeld, package = "plm")
pGrunfeld <- pdata.frame(Grundfeld)
pcdtest(pGrunfeld$inv)

# Pesaran CD test for cross-sectional dependence in panels
# data:  pGrunfeld$inv
# z = 22.922, p-value < 2.2e-16
# alternative hypothesis: cross-sectional dependence
```

The solution suggested by @Christoph Hanck is (and yields the same as it is the same):

```
pcdtest(plm(inv ~ 1 , data = Grunfeld, model = "pooling"))

# Pesaran CD test for cross-sectional dependence in panels
# data:  inv ~ 1
# z = 22.922, p-value < 2.2e-16
# alternative hypothesis: cross-sectional dependence
```